# How to remove background colour from text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[image: Here is what my website looks like:]
As you can see, there is a white background covering the background image. I tried adding `background-color: transparent;` to the text, but nothing happened. How can I get rid of the white background, but still have the text over the background image?

I am using Bootstrap 5.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

html {
  background: url(http://ndquiz.epizy.com/img/worldPersonalProject.png) no-repeat center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.btn-select {
  background-color: #008cba;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.big {
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<main class="text-justify text-center main">
  <h1 class="big">Flag Quiz Game</h1>
  <div>
    <h2>Select Gamemode</h2>
    <a href="">Learn</a>
    <a href="">All (254)</a><br />
    <a href="">All Sovereign (195)</a><br />
    <a href="">Easy (15)</a><br />
    <a href="">Medium (30)</a><br />
    <a href="">Hard (60)</a><br />
    <a href="">Africa (55)</a><br />
    <a href="">Americas (35)</a><br />
    <a href="">Asia (51)</a><br />
    <a href="">Europe (50)</a><br />
    <a href="">Oceania (14)</a><br />
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  Flags from <a href="https://flagpedia.net/" target="_blank">Flagpedia</a>
</footer>
```

Comment: Move the background image to the body tag instead of the html tag and it should work (or remove the white background from your body tag as that's what's causing the issue - you don't actually have a background on the main to start with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting it to

```
background: none !important;
```

Otherwise you could set an RGBA background and put its Alpha channel to 0.

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
```

---

**Summary comments:**

Fix is to move current background settings from `html` to `body` in the CSS.
Original background removal will then work.

Comment: This just gets rid of my background image, I want to keep the image, however I want to remove the white background that covers it.

Comment: Right. Move the background image (currently set to html) into the body. That should fix it. Your original background removal code should work as well then.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these two approaches:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

Or

```
background: url(<yourImage>);
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

You could even use the background as an img and change the opacity:

```
img { 
  opacity: 0.5; 
}
```